# SFML in winform (C++/Cli)

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, picturebox, sfml

How to display sf::Image in PictureBox ?

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(900, 500), "RenderWindow");
sf::Image image;
sf::Texture texture;
sf::Sprite sprite;

image.loadFromFile("D://pic.jpg");
texture.loadFromImage(image);
sprite.setTexture(texture);
```

can we embed RenderedWindow in PictureBox or is there a way to load Sprite , Texture or Image in Picturebox (by creating bitmap)?

i used to load opencv's Iplimage into PictureBox as bitmap using following code

```
IplImage *frame;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;

pictureBox1->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame->width, frame->height, frame->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr) frame->imageData);
```

likewise can we use SFML's Image here..

Comment: Here is an example how to use sfml in c#. C# also uses windowsforms. Maybe you can use it: http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9141.0

Comment: Or just use c++ windows forms, and do exactly what you did in your opencv implementation, using image.getPixelsPtr()

Answer (score 0):

`getPixelsPtr()` is what you're after, docs [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Image.php#ac6137a608a9efaae2735c13ff259c214)